# want bibliographic entries sorted alphabetically

Tags: bibliographies, citing

How can I put the reference in alphabetical order, not in order of apparition in the text?
I'm using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[square,authoryear,sort&compress,semicolon]{natbib}
```

Comment: That depends on your `\bibliographystyle`. `unsrt`/`unsrtnat` for example places them in the order of reference, while `plainnat` I think sorts them alphabetically.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering of the reference should be based on your citation style. When you use numbered referencing, the list should be really in order of apparition (it gets confusing otherwise).

Alphabetically ordered list is used with so called Harvard style of formatting:

> ...study of generalized Bohm criterion (Baalrud et al., 2015) shows...

Example of this using `BibTeX`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
...
...study of generalized Bohm criterion \cite{Baalrud2015} shows...
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{reference}
```

where `reference.bib` contains

```
@article{Baalrud2015,
  author =   {S. D. Baalrud and B. Cheiner and B. Yee and
              M. Hopkins and E. Barnat},
  title =    {Extensions and applications of the Bohm criterion},
  year =     {2015},
  journal =  {Plasma Phys. Control. Fusion},
  volume =   {57},
  pages =    {044003},
  doi =      {10.1088/0741-3335/57/4/044003}
}
```

In this case, the list of all references will be in alphabetical order.